# How do I get the sample deviation from population deviation when sampling is done without replacement from a finite population

Tags: standard-deviation

How do I get the sample deviation from population deviation when sampling is done without replacement from a finite population? The deriving step by step was needed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfZL7.png)

Comment: Do it yourself, adjust formula to $\sigma_{\bar{x}}^2 = \frac{1}{N(N-1)} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (x_i - \mu)^2$ to account for the dependence between the values in the sample, do few simple steps and you'll get $SE(\bar{x}) = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N(N-1)}} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N-1}}$